# Small ProgressDialog "spinner" for android

Tags: android, layout, progressdialog

I've been able to use the standard "ProgressDialog" for android to show that an indeterminate task is running.
[image]

But I'd like to use the "smaller" progress dialog "spinner" that's used for indeterminate tasks in some of the standard Android applications like the android Market (there's a small spinning circle that's actually integrated into the application window (as opposed to floating on top of it).[image]

Does anyone know how to create the smaller progress dialog (or can someone point me in the right direction)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Activity](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/app/Activity.html) class has a built in ProgressBar in the Title area that can be used for this purpose.  Is that what you are referring to?

I assume anywhere else you are seeing this other than in a title bar would just be a [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) UI widget set to indeterminate that is placed in the view.

Comment: Thank you.  I was looking for both of these actually (title area _and_ not in the title area).

Comment: By title bar, are you referring to what I call the "status bar" -- the top of the phone or the titlebar of the application just below the status bar?  I want to spin the one in the status bar.  But then that would be a different question :)

Comment: Application titlebar, not the overall status bar.

Answer (score 1):

Try using ProgressBar and adding it to LinearLayout as follows:

ProgressBar mSpinner = new ProgressBar(this);
        mSpinner.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        mSpinner.setIndeterminate(true);
        lyt.addView(mSpinner);

Answer (score -3):

Use the built in Adnroid widget called ProgressBar. put it on xml layout. and set visibility to visible and invisible as per your requirement